# If element has not class... addClass() to other element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, addclass

I have 2 issues to solve, check following example: http://jsfiddle.net/mmacin/pacJr/5/

1. I need to add class to div, if in other div some class is not present... My code doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if (!$('#menu').hasClass('in')) {
    $('#article').addClass('fWidth');
    }
}
```

2. During "uncollapsing" there is strange effect - double open.

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, previous comment was wrong. But you are still missing a `);` at the end.

Comment: The div has a class "in" to start so it is not going to go into that if....Your code also has syntax errors.

Comment: In your fiddle, #menu has the class .in, so the class fWidth is never added, just as expected

Comment: Try `$('#article').toggleClass('fWidth', $('#menu').is('.in'));`

Comment: I have different solution for this: http://jsfiddle.net/pacJr/14/
But in chrome second point is still annoying me :/

Comment: Ad. 2. There was a problem with !important width. I had to change way of collapsing.. instead of bootstrap collapse i have used toggleClass + CSS transition and display:none.. Simple and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error at the end.
You specify ! before the your if statement.
I think you wanna do something like this, no ?

```
if ($('#menu').hasClass('in') === true) {
 $('#article').addClass('fWidth');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the last closing bracket of the ready function  **)**

It should be,

```
    $( document ).ready(function(){
    if ( !$('#menu').hasClass('in') ) {
        $('#article').addClass('fWidth');
    }
    });
```